# AS3 Error: Access of undefined property Event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm making a game in Flash CS4 using AS3 and I've been trying to make a Play button that works. I already know how to make it work but while debugging I always get "Access of undefined property Event" in compiler errors.

Here's my code:

```
// imports
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// code
stop();

pbtn.addEventListener(EVENT.CLICK, startPlay);

function startPlay(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

I already set the instance name of the button to "pbtn" so it can't be that. I tried both MouseEvent and just Event for the startPlay() function.

I know this must be a really dumb question but I just can't manage to fix this.

Comment: **AS3** is case-sensitive, so it should spell exactly **pbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPlay);** and none other than that. The **EVENT.CLICK** is a wrongful reference to some **EVENT** entity which does not exist.

Comment: Since `function startPlay` is expecting a datatype of **MouseEvent** but your `addEventListener` is sending as **EVENT.CLICK** the correct one should be `MouseEvent.CLICK`...

Comment: @VC.One in fact the first parameter to `addEventListener()` is a mere `String`, so the source could literally be anything. But yes, there is no `Event.CLICK` constant, only a `MouseEvent.CLICK` is present. Anyway, one should plan ahead about what event *type* their code should handle, and use both the exact type in a handler and a proper constant of that type when adding the listener.

Comment: @Vesper Unless you are going to use specific payload data from the event object, it is fine to pass the handler argument as the most basic **Event** class, if it is imported anyway. In certain cases (for the sake of readability and comprehensibility) I devised a single handler for many different types of events with a **switch** by **Event.type** rather than multiple one-two-liner handlers.

Answer (score 0):

`pbtn.addEventListener(EVENT.CLICK, startPlay);`
Just change that line to this
`pbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPlay);`
And its case sensitive so don't change any letter case